# Integration along fibers

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, fiber-bundles

The following statements are  from the book heat kernel and dirac operator chapter 1.

" Let $\pi : M \rightarrow B $ be a fiber bundle with n-dimensional fiber, such that both M and B are oriented. If $\alpha \in {A}_c^k(M)$ is a compactly-supported differential form on M, its integral over the fibers of $ M \rightarrow B $ is the differential form $\int\limits_{M/B} \alpha \in A^{k-n}(B)$ such that

\begin{equation} 
\int\limits_B (\int\limits_{M/B} \alpha) \wedge \beta = \int\limits_M \alpha \wedge \pi^* \beta \quad  ... (1.15)
\end{equation}
for all differential forms $\beta$ on the base B. We sometimes write $ \pi_* \alpha $ instead of $ \int\limits_{M/B} $. It follows easily from the (1.15) that

\begin{equation} 
\pi_*(\alpha \wedge \pi^* \beta ) = \pi_* \alpha \wedge \beta \quad ...(1.16)
\end{equation}
for all $\alpha \in A_c(M) $ and $\beta \in A(\beta).$ "

My questions are the following:

1. what is the intuition behind defining the integral of $\alpha$ over the fibers by the equation (1.15), and why the notion of integration along fiber  is important ?
2. how to prove that equation 1.15 implies equation 1.16 ?

Comment: It's just a generalization of the Fubini theorem for integrating over the product $B\times F$. Indeed, locally any fiber bundle is a product and you reduce to this case with the usual partition of unity argument.

Comment: Write it down in $(x,y)$-coordinates ($x$ on base, $y$ on fiber). You're integrating out all the $dy$. But $\pi^*\beta$ has only $dx$ in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question about why *integration along the fiber* is important, note that it gives a cochain map of degree $-n$,
$$\pi_*: A^k(M) \to A^{k-n}(B).$$
If $M$ was an oriented rank $n$ vector bundle over $B$ then
it can be shown that this map induces isomorphism at the level of cohomology, $H^k(M) \to H^{k-n}(B)$. This is called the *Thom isomorphism*. You can find a proof in Bott & Tu's classic.

Now for your second part, notice that (1.15) is the *defining property* for $\pi_*\alpha$. That is if there were any other form $\omega$, which satisfied (1.15): $\int_B \omega\wedge\beta = \int_M \alpha\wedge\pi^*\beta$ for all $\beta$ (of appropriate degree) on the base, then we would have $\omega = \pi_*\alpha$. So, (1.15) uniquely characterizes $\pi_*\alpha$.

T show that $\pi_*(\alpha\wedge\pi^*\beta) = \pi_*\alpha\wedge\beta$, it suffices to show that $\pi_*\alpha \wedge \beta$ indeed satisfies the defining property (1.15) for $\alpha\wedge\pi^*\beta$. That is we need to show that, for any $\phi \in A^*(B)$.

$$
\int_B (\pi_*\alpha\wedge\beta)\wedge\phi= \int_M (\alpha\wedge\pi^*\beta)\wedge\pi^*\phi
$$

but this is obvious because of the defining property of $\pi_*\alpha$ we have,
$$
\int_B (\pi_*\alpha\wedge\beta)\wedge\phi = \int_B \pi_*\alpha\wedge(\beta\wedge\phi) = \int_M \alpha \wedge \pi^*(\beta\wedge\phi) = \int_M (\alpha \wedge \pi^*\beta)\wedge\pi^*\phi.
$$

Lastly, regarding your comment to @Ted about references, I would suggest Bott & Tu's book. They define integration along the fiber more explicitly using local charts (similar to what Ted was suggesting you to do). Then both (1.15) and (1.16) follow easily from that definition. FWIW, these formulas together are called the *Projection Formulas* (see Proposition 6.15 in Bott & Tu).

Comment: I don't think the Thom isomorphism holds in this situation, since we don't even know what the fiber is.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, Thom isomorphism doesn't hold in this situation. I misread 'n-dimensional fiber' as 'n-dimensional vector space as fiber'. I will correct my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @asma I should add that I haven't seen the book you mentioned in your OP so I don't know what is the motivation behind introducing integration along the fiber at this level of generality (fiber bundles). However, in the special case where your fiber bundles are oriented vector bundles, the importance of the "integration along the fiber"-map is that it gives you the Thom isomorphism.

Comment: @feynhat I think that is an unfair statement. Integral geometry is, in some sense, all about integration over the fiber. Integration over the fiber embodies Poincaré duality (in the compact setting). From a categorical perspective (which I abhor), I suppose (1.15) says that $\pi^*$ and $\pi_*$ are adjoint.

Comment: @TedShifrin I didn't mean to say that the general treatment of integration along the fiber is useless. I was just telling OP about my own lack of knowledge about this. The only place I've seen integration along the fiber is Thom isomorphism for oriented vector bundle.

Comment: @feynhat, thanks a lot for your answer and for the reference, i've greatly appreciate you help .

Comment: @feynhat, i realise now that I didn't understand (in the first answer) why if  there were any other form $\omega$, which satisfied (1.15): $\int_B \omega\wedge\beta = \int_M \alpha\wedge\pi^*\beta$ for all $\beta$ (of appropriate degree) on the base, then we would have $\omega = \pi_*\alpha$. Could you please explain how to prove that $\omega = \pi_*\alpha$ ?

Comment: @asma If there were such an $\omega$ then we would have $\int_B (\omega - \pi_*\alpha)\wedge \beta = 0$ for all $\beta$, but $\int_B (- \wedge -)$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form (by Poincaré duality), so $\omega - \pi_* \alpha = 0$.

Comment: Well this only shows that they are cohomologous but your definition $\pi_*\alpha$ itself only makes sense upto cohomology.

Comment: @feynhat, thanks a lot for your help!